# ¿Cómo sincronizo "develop" y "master" si esta última tiene cambios hardcodeados sin comitear?

Tags: git, git-flow

Me encuentro en una situación un tanto delicada de mi proyecto. Comento lo que ha sucedido:

Un grupo de personas estamos trabajando en un proyecto el cual usa **git flow**. Hemos mantenido los cambios como proceden en gitflow.

Tenemos dos ramas principales: master y develop. Cuando hemos necesitado hemos necesitado hacer cambios creabamos desde develop features para ir avanzando en nuestro desarrollo. Una vez que en  el feature creado veíamos que estaba todo ok lo subíamos a develop.

Una vez teníamos una cantidad considerable de cambios por encima de master hacíamos un release con su respectiva versión.

Hasta aquí todo bien. Pero las exigencias aumentaban y tuvimos que romper el flujo de gitflow, me explico, había cambios que necesitabamos subir cosas determinadas instantáneamente sin pasar por develop. Error tan grave como necesario para seguir adelante.

Entonces ahora me encuentro con que en la rama develop tenemos datos actualizados que en master no hay. Esto sería relativamente sencillo de corregir: un nuevo release y listo. Pero el servidor de producción tiene cambios hechos que al haberse hecho instantáneamente están subidos pero no comiteados. ¿Qué pasa? Pues que cuando intento hacer un release no me deja debido a esos cambios hechos desde el server.

En develop está actualizado pero master tiene cambios hardcodeados que están sin subir al repo pero sí existen y estaba pensando que si subo eso directamente a master mis cambios cuando se suban se verán como cambios anteriores. Y estoy un poco preocupado.

La rama develop está bien.

Comment: Buenas compañero, no tengo mucha experiencia en Git... Pero con TFS se podía crear cambios en "master" y bajarlos hasta "develop", seguramente con Git también se podrá no?
He visto en este sitio web que se puede hacer... Pero no sé si es la misma herramienta que tu estés usando.. https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.es_ES.html  Espero te ayude..!

Answer (score 3):

Si tienes que hacer cambios que van directamente a producción y quieres seguir el estándar git-flow, debes commitearlos en la rama hotfix. Dicha rama tiene que salir inicialmente de master. Esos cambios, cuando suben a producción se mergean **con master y con develop**, de manera que las dos ramas al final contengan los cambios. Si haces un parcheo en producción para salir del paso, pero no quieres que esté en develop, porque más adelante se va a acabar deshaciendo, lo que puedes hacer es después de mergear en develop, revertir el commit que no quieres en develop. De tal manera que en la próxima release se deshará el parcheteo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el gráfico se puede ver un proyecto, donde se empieza a trabajar (commit trabajo) y se mergea en release. Luego la release se mergea en master y se tagea con 1.0 (Este sería el camino "feliz" donde no pasa nada raro)

Después surge un problema en producción, por lo que se crea la rama hotfix para solucionarlo. Hay un fix que es definitivo (parcheteo útil) y otro que se hace para salir del apuro pero que no debería ser definitivo (parcheteo temporal).

Una vez se ha subido a producción se taguea con 1.1 para indicar que ha habido un incremento menor de versión. Se mergea en master y develop.

En develop, nos interesa el parcheteo útil, pero no el temporal. Se han mergeado los dos, por lo que se revierte solamente el temporal y se crea un commit nuevo con el arreglo definitivo del problema.

Finalmente se mergean los cambios de develop en la rama release, y esta en master para crear una versión 2.0 con los problemas solucionados de forma limpia.

Esto es lo que habría que haber hecho con previsión. Si ya se ha liado la cosa, y no puedes/quieres sobreescribir el árbol, puedes usar git cherry-pick para llevar commits individuales de una rama a otra sin tener que mergear una rama y git revert para quitar commits individuales que no necesitan estar en esa rama.

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

Más info:

https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

---

EDIT:

> Mi caso es que se ha tenido
>   que modificar desde el server Linux con el Nano cambios y que como es
>   en el servidor no se han hecho push pues los cambios son instantáneos.
>   Que pasa? Que esos cambios están ahí en producción pero sin subir y yo
>   he seguido trabajando en develop a partir de lo q se supone en máster
>   y digo se supone porque como se cambiaron cosas sin subir hay dos mini
>   versiones del proyecto.

Aquí se pueden dar dos casos, uno que desde tu servidor de linux tengas git y acceso al repositorio, o que no lo tengas.

Si no tienes acceso, lo que tienes que hacer, es en local ir a la rama master y copiar encima los ficheros que has cambiado en tu server linux. Te aparecerán como cambios en rojo al hacer git status.

Creas la rama hotfix si no existe y commiteas y pusheas tu trabajo:

```
1) ¿Existe la rama hotfix?
  1a) No -> git checkout -b hotfix
  1b) Si -> git stash && git checkout hotfix && git merge master && git stash pop
2) git add fichero1 fichero2 fichero3 # Aquí los ficheros involucrados en el hotfix
3) git commit -m "hotfix calentito"
4) git checkout develop
5) git merge --no-ff hotfix
6) git checkout master
7) git merge --no-ff hotfix
8) git push origin master develop hotfix
```

Si tienes acceso, y suponiendo que estas en la rama master, puedes hacer el commit como indica @fedorqui desde el servidor Linux. Los pasos serían los mismos que si no tuvieses acceso pero no necesitarías copiar lógicamente los ficheros a local, y después simplemente te sincronizas en local como si un compañero tuyo hubiese subido cambios.

Comment: Gran respuesta y bien propuesto lo de usar tags para cada versión

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Pero no es mi caso. Mi caso es que se ha tenido que modificar desde el server Linux con el Nano cambios y que como es en el servidor no se han hecho push pues los cambios son instantáneos. Que pasa? Que esos cambios están ahí en producción pero sin subir y yo he seguido trabajando en develop a partir de lo q se supone en máster y digo se supone porque como se cambiaron cosas sin subir hay dos mini versiones del proyecto. Un saludo

Comment: @josanangel ¿Puedes sacar una captura del árbol que tienes? (Si quieres censurar el texto de los commits por privacidad). Así con el árbol a la vista se entiende mejor y podemos ver una solución al problema

Comment: @josanangel cuando haces cambios en producción, ¿ese entorno también trabaja con git? Porque puedes hacer commit desde allí

Comment: @josanangel He ampliado la respuesta con una edición, si puedes échale un ojo a ver si te sirve